# Deleting a specific rows and columns from a data-set using Matlab

Tags: matlab, dataset

I have a large data-set. A sample of this data-set is as follows:

```
213     3      344     54    eloni
45      3      45      34    Trans
224     2      323     332   eloni
343     4      456     345   eloni
456     5      556     45    eloni
```

Let's say, I would like to delete raws contain number (2) on second column or string (Trans) on column number (5).
Can I have a simple code to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for numeric data,

```
 dataset(dataset(:,2)==2,:)=[];
```

More generally,

```
idx=ismember('Trans',dataset(:,5));

dataset(idx,:)=[];
```

Comment: I import my data as a dataset not as Matrix.. It gave me the following error: Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'dataset'.

Comment: See [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/index-and-search-dataset-arrays.html) for how to generalize this to dataset types. You just have to perform the logical indexing in a different way.